# Custom Spring Security OAuth2 with Spring Social integration

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Custom Spring security OAuth2 is working fine and now would like to add Spring Social integration(facebook login, google login etc), When the user clicks on Facebook login(user would not provide any username/password), Facebook will return an access_token, but this access_token we can not use to query my application web services, to get my application access_token we need to pass username and password with grant_type as password. Below are my configuration files

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(
            AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) 
                    throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) 
            throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(86400000);
        tokenServices.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(86400000);
        return tokenServices;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) 
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
        .tokenServices(tokenServices())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private String resourceId = "rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources.resourceId(resourceId);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**/callback").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

and finally **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
      throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() 
      throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**/login").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**/callback").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Have read different posts in SO, but couldn't get any working example, please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Recently i have done similar kind of implementation in one of my projects. I handled it somehow logically. Using the access_token received from Facebook/google, i retrieved the (google/Facebook) profile of the user and then used then retrieved the username from the profile information and then retrieved the access_token from my application using this username.

Comment: How did you configure it?

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Am I right that you want to authenticate your users with Facebook, and then create your own access token for authenticated user to access your backend? If yes, there is a section in [Spring Boot OAuth tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) named "Hosting an Authorization Server". Take a look.

Comment: @yanys thanks for your comment, yes but am not using spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String redirectURL = messages.getProperty(Constant.REDIRECT_URI.getValue());
    String clientSecret = messages.getProperty(Constant.CLIENT_SECRET.getValue());
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String req = "client_id=myas&" + "client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&grant_type=authorization_code&"
            + "scope=user_profile&" + "code=" + loginReqeust.getCode() + "&redirect_uri="
            + loginReqeust.getRedirectURL();

    HttpEntity<String> body = new HttpEntity<String>(req, header);
    Map<Object, Object> mapRes = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();

    // call to get access token
    mapRes = getEndpoint("https://auth.mygov.in/oauth2/token", null, body, null);
    String accessToken = mapRes.get("access_token").toString();


    // Call for getting User Profile

    String userUrl = "https://auth.mygov.in/myasoauth2/user/profile";

    HttpHeaders head = new HttpHeaders();
    head.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    HttpEntity<String> ent = new HttpEntity<String>(head);
    Map<Object, Object> mapResponse = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
    mapResponse.put("userProfile", getEndpoint(userUrl, null, ent, null));

    //In my case userKey represents the username basically the email of the user using which he/she logged into facebook/google

    String userKey = (String) ((LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>) mapResponse.get("userProfile")).get("mail");

    // Store the user profile in your database with basic info like username & an autogenerated password for the time being and other basic fields.

    userService.save(userprofileInfo);                  

                mapResponse.put("username", "retrieved from facebook/google user's profile");
                mapResponse.put("password", "autogenerated by your application");   

    //send back this response (mapResponse) to your UI and then from there make a call by passing this username and pwd to retrieve the access_token from your own applicatioon.
```

Comment: Thanks, am looking to integrate Spring Social with custom OAuth2, this solution is not using spring social.

Comment: I think even with spring social security. You need to provide one endpoint which can be called without your application access_token and that endpoint will retrieve the profile information from Facebook which will have user's Facebook ID which you can use as username of the user and generate an access_token of your application. I assume you create access_token by comparing the username and password from your application database.  So during spring social integration you have to retrieve username from Facebook instead of asking the same from user.

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample, would accept it as an answer and provide the bounty. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure i would give you example by tomorrow once i get time.

Comment: Hi @pushpendra can you please give me some example in spring social if possible

Comment: Hi Ramesh, sorry for delayed response, having super busy schedule for now will still try to provide the example.

Comment: Pushpendra can you give me an example.!

Comment: Hi @pushpendra can you please give me some example in spring social if possible

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to get an access token from facebook and generate own JWT token by validating the facebook token on the server side.

I modified the project mentioned here:
https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt

My customizations are as follows(I am assuming you already have a facebook access token):

**LoginRequest.java**

```
public class LoginRequest {
private String token;

@JsonCreator
public LoginRequest(@JsonProperty("token") String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
}
```

**AjaxLoginProcessingFilter.java**

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    if (!HttpMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod()) || !WebUtil.isAjax(request)) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Authentication method not supported. Request method: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        throw new AuthMethodNotSupportedException("Authentication method not supported");
    }

    LoginRequest loginRequest = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), LoginRequest.class);

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(loginRequest.getToken())) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("token not provided");
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getToken(), null);

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}
```

**AjaxAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Autowired private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
@Autowired private DatabaseUserService userService;


@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    Assert.notNull(authentication, "No authentication data provided");
    String username = null;
    try {
        username = getUsername(authentication.getPrincipal());
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    //You can either register this user by fetching additional data from facebook or reject it.        
    User user = userService.getByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));

    if (user.getRoles() == null) throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("User has no roles assigned");

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getRole().authority()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    UserContext userContext = UserContext.create(user.getUsername(), authorities);

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userContext, null, userContext.getAuthorities());
}

private String getUsername(Object principal) throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //I am just accessing the details. You can debug whether this token was granted against your app.
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + principal.toString());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());

    //This is just for demo. You should use id or some other unique field.
    String username = o.getString("first_name");
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
}
```

Apart from this, I also had to add custom BeanPostProcessor to override the default behavior of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to accept only token as a field instead of a username and a password.

**UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor.java**

public class UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor    {

```
private String usernameParameter;
private String passwordParameter;

@Override
public final Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean,
    final String beanName) {
    return bean;
}

@Override
public final Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean,
    final String beanName) {
    if (bean instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) {
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter =
            (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) bean;
        filter.setUsernameParameter(getUsernameParameter());
        filter.setPasswordParameter(getPasswordParameter());
    }

    return bean;
}

public final void setUsernameParameter(final String usernameParameter) {
    this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
}

public final String getUsernameParameter() {
    return usernameParameter;
}

public final void setPasswordParameter(final String passwordParameter) {
    this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
}

public final String getPasswordParameter() {
    return passwordParameter;
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor  userPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor(){
    UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor bean = new UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor();
    bean.setUsernameParameter("token");
    bean.setPasswordParameter(null);
    return bean;
}
```

[image: postman output]

Comment: i have a form where user can either enter username/password or click on social network icon, for manual login process am able to generate the OAuth2 access token, am using spring security, trying to integrate spring social.

Comment: If you want to use both manual and social authentication then don't override the default behavior of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter as I suggested. Instead configure two different auth URL and processing filter for manual and social login. To login manually send username and password and for social login send token as username and password null and then handle it accordingly in social login filter. As far as spring social login is concerned it is currently supporting provider tokens only.